# Tag future report

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, statistics

I came across https://math.stackexchange.com/users/tag-future/current which represents a recent attempt by SE to understand what types of questions each user is likely to answer. (The underlying motivation being to feed more questions of the kind to the user.)

Having found that I'm  considered a **high activity** user (in bold font, no less), I had to ask: is this the top level, or can I do better?

> Have you reached a status above  "high activity"?  (I don't know what it would be called: *very high*, *extremely high*, or *get a life*...)

[image]

Comment: I'm a high activity user as well, so I doubt there's any other level. I practically live here.

Comment: My report says I prefer to avoid questions tagged "probability" --- but I have a tag-badge for it anyway. Curious.

Comment: I don't sure that the predictor is considering favourite or ignored tags - apparently, I'm likely to answer homework questions even though they're on my ignore list.

Comment: How did you came across that?